# Add metadata to S3 Object, while keeping existing metadata and ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata, acl, aws-php-sdk

I'm looking for a way to programmatically add specific metadata to a set of S3 objects. I've recently updated the code in my project to set the 'Cache-Control: max-age' and 'Expires' when uploading objects to S3, but now I'm trying to set those values for my existing S3 objects.  I don't want anything else to change, such as the ACL or any other metadata.

I had tried using the AWS CLI to achieve this, but run into a couple issues. My bucket has both public and non-public objects, so I cannot just set the acl to 'public-read'. I want the ACL to remain unchanged, but if I set nothing, they all become private. Also, I want to add metadata, but keep any existing metadata intact. Here's the cli call I had tried:

`aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket s3://my-bucket --acl public-read --recursive --metadata-directive=REPLACE --cache-control max-age=2592000 --expires 'Wed, 29 July 2020 00:00:01 GMT'`

I am using the AWS PHP SDK, but am open to other methods.

For maintaining the same metadata, I've tried using `headObject` to get existing header data... but it give back a lot of values. I can iterate over them, but I don't know which ones I'd need to set again to maintain everything.

For maintaining the same ACL, I have tried using `getObjectAcl` followed by `putObjectAcl`... but I'm pretty sure this isn't going to work in all cases (I'm pretty sure my logic for setting the `ACL` value as `public-read` or `private` isn't robust enough for all cases...).

```
$acl_result = $s3->getObjectAcl([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $object_key
]);

$grants = $acl_result->get('Grants');
$owner = $acl_result->get('Owner');

...

$public = false;
foreach($grants as $grant){
    if(isset($grant['Grantee']['URI'])
        && $grant['Grantee']['URI'] == 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers'
        && $grant['Permission'] == 'READ'){
        $public = true;
    }
}
$object = [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $object_key,
    'ACL'    => ($public ? 'public-read' : 'private'),
    'AccessControlPolicy'    => [
        'Owner' => $owner,
        'Grants' => $grants,
    ],
];
$s3->putObjectAcl($object);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!